# Manage a cassandra database on docker with opscenter

Tags: database, docker, cassandra, opscenter, nosql

I have a cassandra instance running on Docker and I am wondering (if possible) to use datastax opscenter to monitor the cassandra instance.

To cennect to my cassandra instance I run:

```
$ docker run -it --rm cassandra:3.0.2 bash
$ cqlsh [MY_HOST] -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD
```

After installing `opscenter` I dont know what to put here:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use OpsCenter to monitor your cassandra instance you will need to have the Datastax-agent running on your cassandra instance. You then add the IP address of the running cassandra instance to the dialog box in your post. Click Save Cluster and OpsCenter will try to connect to your cassandra instance.

If this is the free version of OpsCenter it will have some limitations like only managing a single node instance, but I have done what your asking so  you should be able to connect to your cassandra instance and it should come up in opscenter.

Give it a try, hope this helps.
Pat